# Angular Material Dialog modal error

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

this is the first time working with angular 4 and material design, im trying to create a modal window with angular material design and have this two files:

**roomlist.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { RoomService } from '../../services/room.service';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { RoomDialogComponent } from './dialogs/roomDialogs/room.dialog';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-roomlist',
  templateUrl: './roomlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./roomlist.component.css']
})
export class RoomlistComponent implements OnInit {
  public rooms: any;
  public roomsFilter = {
    date: new Date,
    aviable: 'all',
    globalSeach: ''
  };
  constructor(public roomService: RoomService, public dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  public getData(): any {
    console.log(this.roomsFilter.date);
    this.roomService.getRooms({ date: 'now' })
      .then((res) => {
        this.rooms = res;
        console.log(this.rooms);
      });
  }

  public openDialog(event, room): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(RoomDialogComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data: room
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }

}
```

and this one: **room.dialog**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Dialog Overview
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'app-room-dialog',
  templateUrl: './room.dialog.html',
})
export class RoomDialogComponent {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<RoomDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

the modal should open when i press a button that is trigger the function openDIalog but im geting this error message `No component factory found for RoomDialogComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

any idea

Comment: You have an unnecessary `)` in  `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }`

Comment: no there is not extra `)` the last one is from the constructor and the other from the `@inject()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you do what the error said?

Did you add it to entry components????

```
@NgModule({
entryComponents: [
    YourDialogComponent
  ]
})
```

Comment: Yeap that was it, angular material documentation is no to clear of how to use some components

Comment: but it did literally ask you "Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?"... so there's that.. but i agree with you.

Comment: Sorry maybe i miss read, i see `declaration` no `entryComponents`.

Comment: just add it to ngModule like i stated

Comment: @MiguelAngelFrias There's literally a section on adding your dialog to `entryComponents`: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#aot-compilation (Scroll to AOT Compilation section if hash doesn't work)